# Settings app of ubuntu 18.04 shows kali instead ubuntu in about section

Tags: ubuntu

After installing katoolin My ubuntu 18.04 started to download software from kali repositories and i could not add any repository. But i fixed those by changing some files in /etc/... . But When i go to about section of gnome-control-center, it shows Kali GNU/Linux instead of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS . I am unable to fix that
Please help.[Screenshot of about settings is provided in link so that you guys can get my problem clearly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11YIP.png)

Comment: This is not a programming question. I suggest deleting it and posting in [ubuntu.se].

Comment: This is not about programming, belongs to [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change /etc/os-release and /etc/lsb-release file with file on any other computer with same distro